# Xcopy folder selection

Tags: batch-file, directory, xcopy

I would like to make an automated task by using a .bat file in order to copy some files from the server to users' computers. The destination of the files can be on different partitions but the location (folder-wise) is the same.

For example I have 1 file I want to copy from the server to `C:\Program Files\Program` or `D:\Program Files\Program` (note that the path, apart from the partition is the same)

Comment: Should the batch file select randomly where to copy? Should it be selected based on some criteria? Should the user be asked? ....

Comment: The batch file should copy to the folder specified but the partition may vary. The files are preselected and no the user should have no interference

Comment: How will the batch file decide whether to copy to C:\SOMEWHERE or D:\SOMEWHERE?

Comment: Use %SystemDrive% instead of C:/ or D:/ so it would read "%SystemDrive%\Program Files\Program"

Comment: Is it possible to make it decide? Can it do like a search for a specific path? As with a variable

Comment: Where are you going to run the script from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work if you're running it from the server with admin rights.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%a in (computer1 computer2 computer3) do (
  for %%b in (c d) do (
    if exist "\\%%a\%%b$\Program Files\Program\." (
      xcopy /F /I "yourfile.ext" "\\%%a\%%b$\Program Files\Program"
    )
  )
)
```

If you're running it from a workstation, you could do something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%a in (c d) do (
  if exist "%%a:\Program Files\Program\." (
      xcopy /F /I "\\Server\Share\yourfile.ext" "%%a:\Program Files\Program"
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I didn't know how to interchange the partitions

Answer (score 1):

This will copy a few files:

```
copy "\\server\share\*.txt" "%ProgramFiles%\target folder\"
```

This will copy a folder tree:

```
xcopy "\\server\share\folder\*.*" "%ProgramFiles%\target folder\" /s/h/e/k/f/c/z
```

The `%ProgramFiles%` variable holds the location of the installations program files folder.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a basic copy from one dir to another like this.

**For a file**

```
@echo off
echo copying files
copy /Y C:\Program Files\Program\TheFileYouWantToCopy.file  D:\Program Files\Program\TheFileYouWantToCopy.file
echo copying files done.
pause
goto :eof
```

Replace "TheFileYouWantToCopy.file" with as it says the file you want to copy.

**For a dir**

If you want to copy a dir from one place to another use this:

```
@Echo Off 
Echo Please Press "d"
xcopy "C:\Program Files\Program" "D:\Program Files\Program" 
Echo done
pause
goto :eof
```

**In response to comments:**

Try %SystemDrive%\Program Files\Program as your path. %SystemDrive% is just where the system stores its files and that can be anything from A:/ to Z:/.

Comment: No I want to copy a file to the same destination folder wise like: "...:\Program Files\Program" where ... can be either C or D. Thing is that users have this Program installed on either partition and I don't know which so the xcopy syntax has to be of a general form.